# Exporting to PDF-blank PDF

Tags: qgis, export, pdf

Could someone help me with determining how to export to PDF using QGIS 2.18.13 and my PDF viewer/editor is Foxit?

When exporting to PDFs, it is now blank. I have exported before with no problems. I have tried to do a jpeg, same thing, blank. Exporting to SVG, not blank but text is badly distorted/large in size. I have take text boxes out, still blank pdf. I have updated QGIS, I was using 2.18.1 at first, but I started getting blank PDFs before the update also.

Comment: Could you tell us step by step what your export process is?

Comment: I created a print composer, sheet set up to 36 by 24, added scael, legend, etc.. The print composer was already set up from previous time I successfully exported to PDF. Even created a new print composer. Clicked export to PDF, creates PDF but blank even with new print composer.

Comment: Are you using wms layers as basemaps? perhaps it could be a problem with the DPI setting

Comment: I am using WMS layers as basemaps, where is the DPI setting?

Comment: Found the dpi setting, change to 300, still blank PDF

Comment: @QuinnB.  try to input a lower DPI (like 100, or 150)

Comment: Thank you, I meant to comment on here earlier, only works with 120 dpi or lower. Thanks again for the feedback/suggestion/solution.

Comment: I'm posting it as an answer so you can accept it @QuinnB.

Answer (score 1):

When using WMS layers, there are some limitations with the DPI values in the print composer.

If exporting a map with WMS services results in a blank file, it means that the WMS service is "exportable" only with a less DPI value.

Try to lower down the DPI value of the exported map until the WMS will be finally displayed.